# SQL Script to take a Microsoft Sql database online or offline?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, offline

If I wish to take an MS Sql 2008 offline or online, I need to use the GUI -> DB-Tasks-Take Online or Take Offline.

Can this be done with some sql script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
ALTER DATABASE database-name SET OFFLINE
```

If you run the [ALTER DATABASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275464(SQL.80).aspx) command whilst users or processes are connected, but you do not wish the command to be blocked, you can execute the statement with the NO_WAIT option. This causes the command to fail with an error.

```
ALTER DATABASE database-name SET OFFLINE WITH NO_WAIT
```

Corresponding online:

```
ALTER DATABASE database-name SET ONLINE
```

Answer (score 4):

```
-- Take all user databases offline
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_TakeOfflineAllDatabase AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @db sysname, @q varchar(max);
    DECLARE cur_db CURSOR FOR
        SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE owner_sid<>0x01;
    OPEN cur_db;
    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_db INTO @db;
        IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
            BREAK;
        SET @q = N'ALTER DATABASE [' + @db + N'] SET OFFLINE WITH NO_WAIT';
        EXEC(@q);
    END;
    CLOSE cur_db;
    DEALLOCATE cur_db;
END;
```

Restart the server before run the procedure. It will close the existed connections to the databases.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post but, just in case someone comes across this solution and would prefer a non cursor method which does not execute but returns the scripts.
I have just taken the previous solution and converted it into a select that builds based on results.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @SQL=COALESCE(@SQL,'')+'ALTER DATABASE  '+name+ N' SET OFFLINE WITH NO_WAIT;
    '
FROM sys.databases
WHERE owner_sid<>0x01
PRINT @SQL
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a note that just might be very usefull to you :
It's almost always possible to see what the GUI is doing TSQLwise behind the scenes.

c :  http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1505

Comment: Nod Peter - i use that button (to grab scripts) all the time ... a good example of that is when i wish to change the table structure/schema, and it takes more than 30 seconds (default wait time before a timeout error is raised) .. so i need to grab the change script and run it manually.